# ms sql 2012+ : Is there a better way to reference outer query within the subquery?

Tags: sql-server

This join syntax works when referencing sysJobHistory jh within the subquery's instance hi, however is there a better way to do this? I know in mssql2014 where t1.x = t2.x will be deprecated.

```
    select distinct j.Name as "Job Name", 
        case j.enabled 
            when 1 then 'Enable' 
            when 0 then 'Disable' 
        end as "Job Status", 
        jh.run_date as [Last_Run_Date(YY-MM-DD)] , 
        case jh.run_status 
            when 0 then 'Failed' 
            when 1 then 'Successful' 
            when 2 then 'Retry'
            when 3 then 'Cancelled' 
            when 4 then 'In Progress' 
        end as Job_Execution_Status
      from msdb.dbo.sysJobHistory jh 
       inner join msdb.dbo.sysJobs j
        on j.job_id = jh.job_id
      where jh.run_date =  
        (select max(hi.run_date) 
          from msdb.dbo.sysJobHistory hi 
           where jh.job_id = hi.job_id
             and jh.run_date >= 20140316
         ) 
        and jh.run_status = 3 or j.enabled = 0
        and jh.run_date >= 20140316
```

Comment: I don't think they would deprecate standard ANSI co-related sub-query functionality, would they? Anyway, this, or a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY hi.run_date DESC)` in a CTE with your nested query, then a join to it where the row number = 1 and your other constraints is my usual approach.

Comment: I did not look at your query. What do you want to do ? What is the output that you expect ?

Comment: @Cory, thanks for answering--hopefully the co-related sub-query functionality will stay, although i don't know for sure. I know the old school t1.x = t2.x for the main query is going away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above; the way you've done it with a correlated sub-query is a typical solution. The other approach I sometimes take is ranking the data found in the sub-query and then joining to it:

```
with history as (
    select 
      run_date,
      /* Rank the rows grouped by the job_id */
      row_number() over (partition by job_id order by run_date desc) as rownum
    from msdb.dbo.sysJobHistory 
)
select distinct j.Name as "Job Name", 
    case j.enabled 
        when 1 then 'Enable' 
        when 0 then 'Disable' 
    end as "Job Status", 
    jh.run_date as [Last_Run_Date(YY-MM-DD)] , 
    case jh.run_status 
        when 0 then 'Failed' 
        when 1 then 'Successful' 
        when 2 then 'Retry'
        when 3 then 'Cancelled' 
        when 4 then 'In Progress' 
    end as Job_Execution_Status
  from msdb.dbo.sysJobHistory jh 
   inner join msdb.dbo.sysJobs j
    on j.job_id = jh.job_id
  /* Join to the "newest" instance of the job_id by selecting the correct rank */
   inner join history hi
    on jh.job_id = hi.job_id
    and hi.rownum = 1
  where jh.run_status = 3 or j.enabled = 0
    and jh.run_date >= 20140316
```